Volume of a truncated ellipsoid by a plane
I am working on measuring volumes of medieval architectural figures that protrude from the walls as a decoration or with a certain cultural message.
I am interested in the intersection of the ellipsoid
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
and the plane $$Ax+By+Cz= D$$
where $a,b,c,A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}$.
There is a similar question on this site, but in the form of inequality, cite: Ray Bern (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/518963/ray-bern), Volume of a truncated ellipsoid, URL (version: 2018-01-06): Volume of a truncated ellipsoid
I have tested many numerical approachs and the solution works:
$V=abc \frac13 \pi (4 - (1 -|d|)^2 (2+|d|))$
where $d=D/\sqrt{(Aa)^2+(Bb)^2+(Cc)^2}$
and $|d| < 1$.
My question is if the equation works in all cases and the demostration is the same as the inequality, given by cite: Andreas (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317854/andreas), Volume of a truncated ellipsoid, URL (version: 2024-04-30): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2599275
Thanks in advance
